# VmWare Exsi 5.0 - Which folder is the iso image located?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I need to download an ISO image to the Exsi 5.0 server directly using wget and I am just wondering which folder I need to download the iso to?

Comment: What ISO-file? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You should never download something directly to the ESX Server. However, if you really need to, then you can save it to any Folder you want... Preferrable in a datastore Folder `(/vmfs/*)`

Comment: My home internet connection is slow and it will take me at least hours to download the iso image and twice that time to upload at least, I need the iso image to install the OS for the virtual machine created

Answer (score 2):

If this is for instance a boot CD/DVD image for an OS you want to install just use the VSClient.exe application, select a datastore, choose browse datastore and then upload it somewhere in there. You can then browse to that location from the VM's settings/CD-drive dialogue.

Comment: My home internet connection is slow and it will take me at least hours to download the iso image and twice that time to upload at least, I need the iso image to install the OS for the virtual machine created, so I really don't think using the vSphere client is a good idea....

Comment: I think what you're doing is a terrible idea but if you absolutely insist then follow MichelZ's recommendation and be sure to place it in a VMFS formatted datastore. You do know ESXi isn't designed to be treated like a linux box and that any linux-like functionality could just be removed at any point with updates right?